# Multiplication of two density functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $f$ and $g$ are density functions, is $fg$ (i.e., $fg(x) = f(x)g(x)$) a probability density function?

Provided we have a constant b such that $0<b<1$ and Is $bf +(1-b)g$ a probability density function.

I put a thought to it.. and according to me its just a composition of two density functions so it should too be a density function. But it isn't. Can some please enlighten and explain me why?

Comment: What do you mean by "composition of two density functions"?  If you meant $f(x)g(y)$, then the answer is yes, it is a density function, namely that of $(X,Y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are two independent RVs with density fct $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 2):

> Is $fg$ a PDF?

No, e.g. $f=g=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\frac{-x^2}{2}$. I think you have [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) in mind. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Properties).

> $Is bf+(1-b)g a PDF?

Yes because $\int_{\Bbb R}(bf+(1-b)g)dx=b+1-b=1$ & the integrand $\ge b0+(1-b)0=0$.

Comment: Yes, exactly that was my point. I think I got a little confused with convolution and composition.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the uniform distribution on $[0,1/2]$. The density function is
\begin{equation*}
p(x)=\begin{aligned}
\begin{cases}
2 & \text{if $x\in[0,1/2]$},\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Multiplying this density function by itself gives
\begin{equation*}
p^2(x)=\begin{aligned}
\begin{cases}
4 & \text{if $x\in[0,1/2]$},\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Thus, $p^2$ does not integrate to one, and therefore cannot be a density function.

For your second question, let $p$ and $q$ be density functions and let $\theta\in[0,1]$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\int (\theta p(x) + (1-\theta)q(x))dx = \theta\int p(x)dx + (1-\theta)\int q(x)dx = \theta+(1-\theta)=1,
\end{equation*}
and $\theta p(x)+(1-\theta)q(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$, since $p$ and $q$ are nonnegative and $\theta\in[0,1]$. Hence, the convex combination is a density function.

Comment: Thanks Man! Examples do give a better clarity

Comment: Mmm... the product of two pdf is not a density. Indeed it comes down to consider the geometric average of two pdfs. If you want this geometric average to be a pdf, you need the sum of weights equals one. In the example above, the sum of weight equals 2 and so the resulting function is not a pdf but if you take $f_1(x)=p(x)^a$ and $f_1(x)=p(x)^{1-a}$, the product $f_1 \times f_2$ is a density... I wonder if this reasoning works a generic density function...