# Is the geometric average of two densities functions a density function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, density-function

Following the question of the topic [Multiplication of two density functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3775968/multiplication-of-two-density-functions),
i wonder if the weighted geometric average of two probability density functions (pdfs) is itself a density ? More formally, if i have two pdfs $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$, is the product function $g(x)$ defined like:
$$g(x) = f_1(x)^{a} \times f_2(x)^{1-a}$$ a density with $a$ a real number not necessearily comprised between $0$ and $1$ ?

Comment: The answer is no, usually not, as the integral is usually not $1$.  You could "normalise" the result.  If $a<0$ or $a >1$ you will also want to avoid division by $0$

Comment: @Henry Have you an example in mind of two pdfs not giving a pdf while both in the formula above ?

Comment: @Henry is the fact powers a and 1-a sums to one sufficient to normalize the result ? In fact, as a weighted arithmetic average of pdfs is a density when all the weights sums to one, i wonder if there are other kinds of weighted averages (geometric, harmonic, etc.) the two densities that also produces a pdf when the weights sums to 1 (or to any other specific quantity designed to normalize the resulting density).

Comment: As a simple example, take $f_1(x)=2x$ and $f_2(x)=2(1-x)$ on $[0,1]$ and $a=\frac12$.  You get $g(x)=2\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ and $\int\limits_0^1 g(x)\, dx= \frac \pi 4$ so $g(x)$ is not a probability density.  But $h(x)=\frac4\pi g(x) =\frac8\pi \sqrt{x(1-x)}$ is a probability density